# Typical Maven Deploy Plugin for Nexus from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, repository

I would like to put a project on the nexus repository on sonatype (oss.sonatype.or) directly from eclipse using the deploy-plugin. I was close, but no cigar. I can build the -source.jar, and the -javadoc.jar files, and get everything signed with gpg-plugin, but when I deployed there were some errors. Can anyone share a typical pom.xml for this? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you provide the error that occured? I know you are new, but try to keep in mind that some research on your part goes a *long way* to helping you out. Did you try anything so far? Please show your efforts first so that other people might help you out. Also, please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: Attach log with error message.

Comment: What mean *two sep. 'repositories'*? Do you mean `snapshots` and `releases`? And where is your error? Remote repository is only one, when your project has snapshot version (ex `1.0-SNAPSHOT`) then repository `snapshots` is used.

Comment: No. In the Sonatype Nexus website, when you deploy, it makes a repository. They have a number, such as client-1000. When I deploy, I get two repositories, with two numbers, such as client-1001, client-1002. In essence, there are two separate uploads being done for one deploy.

Comment: Ok, but where is this described in your question? Are you tried with `nexus-staging-maven-plugin`?

Comment: It's not. I tried asking that an no one answered. So, instead, I asked what was typical for Eclipse. (I think you are running from the command line?) The POM below is a good example of typical, even it doesn't work from within Eclipse. I am using it and have marked it up as a good answer. Thanks.

Comment: Im sure it is working from Eclipse too - usage is transparent, dosent matter how you invoke `deploy` goal. Thanks for accepting.

Comment: About maven from eclipse: *you can configure m2eclipse to use external Maven installation when launching Maven using "Run as… / Maven XXX" actions.* from M2E FAQ

Comment: Thanks: it may be specific to oss.sonatype.org or a repository that is not in-house. I saw that two other users on sonatype ask the same question, but they said it worked the next time, and so no follow up. There is definitely something inconsistent about it.

Comment: I think there are valid questions in this post, but the way it is written they are hard to find. Consider rewording it to make others benefit more from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update: Per request: Detailed instructions for Setting up Eclipse to Deploy to Maven Central Repository (repo1.maven.org)**

Start with an Eclipse Java Project. Convert it to a Maven project using m2e. 
The requirements for deploying a useful library to the Central Repository are

**1:** Good code. Just use common sense. Don’t put garbage up there. Test it.

**2:** Javadocs. Comment all your classes and methods. Create a **/src/main/javadoc** directory. Use a javadoc plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-javadocs</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

**3:** Source Code: Use a source code plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-sources</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

**4:** Get a gpg id and key and get it ‘registered’ by following the Sonatype instructions for setting it up with Maven: see
https://docs.sonatype.org/display/Repository/How+To+Generate+PGP+Signatures+With+Maven
  Add plugin …

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>sign</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

And .m2/settings.xml

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>gpg</id>
        <properties>
            <gpg.passphrase>*******</gpg.passphrase>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>gpg</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
```

**5:** Add maven deploy plugin. This stops the regular deploy phase:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <skip>true</skip>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**6:** Add sonatype plugin: Note: you will be able to get he stagingProfileId once you have been granted access to the repository.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <serverId>sonatype-nexus-staging</serverId>
        <nexusUrl>https://oss.sonatype.org/</nexusUrl>
        <stagingProfileId>***********</stagingProfileId>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**7:** Read the Sonatype Maven Repository usage guide carefully: Do the extra things that your POM needs, such as a licenses section, scm section, developers section, and parent section.
https://docs.sonatype.org/display/Repository/Sonatype+OSS+Maven+Repository+Usage+Guide
It will tell you how to sign up and open a ticket. Once you have a ticket open, then you have access to the Sonatype Nexus site at https://oss.sonatype.org. That is where you can find your stagingProfileId that is needed above. Add the server information to your .m2/settings.xml

```
<servers>
    <server>
        <id>sonatype-nexus-snapshots</id>
        <username>yourusername</username>
        <password>yourpassword</password>
    </server>
    <server>
        <id>sonatype-nexus-staging</id>
        <username>yourusername</username>
        <password>yourpassword</password>
    </server>
</servers>
```

**8:** Finally, from eclipse, create a maven runtime configuration: Right click on the project, choose Run As->Run Configurations. Create a new Maven Build, set the base directory to your project directory, and the goals as “clean deploy”  Apply and run, but first run Mavin->Install to create your javadocs and source files locally so you can check for errors or warning messages.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation about staging

- http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/staging-sect-deployment.html

This is snippet from my working configuration (without stagging)

### pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <groupId>com.company.sample</groupId>
        <artifactId>sample-app</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>attach-sources</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>jar</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>jar</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>

        <distributionManagement>
            <repository>
                <id>nexus</id>
                <url>https://repository.company.com/content/repositories/releases/</url>
            </repository>
            <snapshotRepository>
                <id>nexus</id>
                <url>https://repository.company.com/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
            </snapshotRepository>
        </distributionManagement>

    </project>
```

### ~/.m2/settings.xml

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>nexus</id>
            <username>admin</username>
            <password>secret_password</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
</settings>
```

### Command for deploy to maven repository

```
mvn deploy
```

For attaching source:jar and javadoc:jar use configuration from [Cookbook: How to attach source and javadoc artifacts?](http://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/cookbook/attach-source-javadoc-artifacts.html)

Comment: Thanks MarieszS. Do you have any entries for the 'build' part of the pom that are relevant? I think that I need to add a few there so as to get the javadoc and source jars created and signed. Is that not true?

Comment: Im using `maven-release-plugin` (configuration added) for deploying. I dont have configuration for signing.

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/cookbook/attach-source-javadoc-artifacts.html

Comment: Well, I tried the release plugin, but it needs command-line maven, which I don't think I want to install if I'm running from eclipse. This question was about the deploy-plugin. Thanks though.

Comment: Ok, attached configuration for javadoc and source jar. This solution is WORKING with `mvn deploy`. If not, copy paste error from console.

Comment: `mvn deploy` upload `jar`, `source.jar` and `javadoc.jar` to remote repository. Release plugin uses deploy plugin for uploading. I dont understand your problem now.

Comment: `source` and `javadoc` is attached to `jar` goal, this mean when jar is builded, then also `source` and `javadoc`. In result project has three artifacts and deploy plugin upload all three artifact to remote server.

Comment: Yes, I have three artifacts too, but they get uploaded in two separate uploads. So, I can't close the repository.

Comment: Why uploading in two upload is problem? I dont understand.

Comment: The client-jar and the client.jar.asc, for example, ended up in two different repositories. Neither repository could be closed for release.